# Remove white background from custom button android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-styles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#000066" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#3333D6" />
        <corners
            android:radius="50dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#1919FF"
            android:endColor="#7171FF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners
            android:radius="50dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This is the code I use to style some buttons , but they still appear  with that ugly background (white) like this: http://prntscr.com/65yzgv

How can I get rid of this white background?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? The proposed solution didn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to the fact that you are probably compiling the button with lollipop,i.e., API 21, in which shadow is by default.

So, try the way I did it (basically, set its style to 'borderless') :

yourcustombutton.xml (same as your file) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#000066" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#3333D6" />
        <corners
            android:radius="50dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#1919FF"
            android:endColor="#7171FF"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners
            android:radius="50dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Button Declared in your activity file :

```
...
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Answer 1"
    android:background="@drawable/yourcustombutton"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
     />
...
```

This is working fine... I checked it. Hope this helps !

Comment: Ya, never thought that he might be working on Lollipop.. I guess going ahead, people should mention that as well because there are quite a few significant changes in the material design..
Anyways, removing stroke will get him rid off the white border as well, if thats whats a concern too..

Answer (score 1):

To make a background transparent, just add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in your button properties in the layout xml file its defined in.

Comment: in which line exactly?

Comment: In the properties... something like... <Button android:id="@+id/MyButton" android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

Comment: Got it? Or still clueless?

Comment: @Saurabh If he adds background to transparent, then how will he add desired background given by him in his code ??

Comment: Good Catch Abhinav.. I just now tried his code and realised that it's not showing me that kind of weird White Background in a rectangular shape.. Its just giving a rounded white border which is in alignment with the shape of the button.. This white border can be avoided by removing the stroke..

Answer (score 0):

In button add:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: It's not correct to use a null background!! The Android API provides the correct attribute to create a transparent background without losing the visual feedback for button clicked or for the other states!